# Bost's slopes method for Lindemann theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Hello,

I am looking for a proof of Lindemann theorem (transcendence of $e^a$ for $a$ algebraic) that uses Bost's slopes method. Does anyone know where I could find that?

Comment: Can you give us a reference for "Bost's slopes method"? 

Comment: Here is a link from Sémainaire de Bourbaki: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0103192.pdf

Comment: Have you tried searching Math Reviews for keywords Lindemann and Bost?

Comment: I did. But nothing appeared unfortunately

Comment: So, maybe what you are looking for, doesn't exist. Do you have some reason to believe there is a proof of Lindemann somewhere that uses Bost?